# Kendo UI grid ClientTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, client-templates

I'm binding client templates to columns in my kendo ui grid as you see below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("marketWatchGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.direction).ClientTemplate(
                    "# if (direction==1) {#" +
                        "▲" + 
                    "#}#" +
                    "# if (direction==0) {#" +
                        "▼" + 
                    "#}#"
                ).Title("").Width(30);
            columns.Bound(p => p.symbol).ClientTemplate("<a href='javascript:selectSymbol('" + "#: symbol #" +"')'>#: symbol #</a>"); ;
            columns.Bound(p => p.bid);
            columns.Bound(p => p.ask);
        })
        .Scrollable()
    )
```

The following template does not work:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.symbol).ClientTemplate("<a href='javascript:selectSymbol('" + "#: symbol #" +"')'>#: symbol #</a>"); ;
```

I'm getting Javascript syntax error. How can I fix this?

Comment: that's not a kendo ui definition.  That's mvc code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed my template to:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.symbol).ClientTemplate("<a href=javascript:selectSymbol(\'" + "#: symbol #" +"\')>#: symbol #</a>");
```

It works fine now.

Comment: May i ask a question please? I wanted to know that Is there anything special in Kendo Grid, which is not possible in regular JQuery min files ?

Comment: So it was only a typo in the quote escape. Ugly about this it, that its not HTML XML complaint because your href attribute is not quoted anymore.

Comment: @hellyeah, it is *not* acceptable for you to edit another user's question or answer in order for you to display it the way that you prefer... do that in *your own question or answer*, not someone else's. If you think that a change should be made, then leave a comment suggesting that the *user* changes their own post.

Comment: @Sheridan sorry for the most probably unnecessary edit, I was carried away by the wiki spirit. I just wanted to remove the superfluous string concatenation on the answer

Comment: That's fine... we all have to learn some time. For more information on when it *is* appropriate to edit someone else's post, please see the [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) page from the StackOverflow [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). In order to get the most out of this site, it might be an idea to read through some of the other pages too.